# GCM/FCM : How to update status bar notifications without annoying users if notification is already being shown by GCM/FCMListener#onMessageReceived()?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice, gcm-network-manager

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    dbhelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/teta")) {
        if (message != null) {

            final Alert alert = new Gson().fromJson(message, Alert.class);

            Log.d(TAG, alert.getDesc() + " " + alert.getLink() + " " + alert.getTimeStamp() + " " + alert.getTitle());

            dbhelper.addAlertsToDB(alert, DatabaseHelper.NEW);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(AppPreferences.NEW_ALERT_RECIEVED));

            boolean notifPref = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(AppPreferences.PREFERENCE_RECIEVE_NOTIFICATION, false);
            if (notifPref) {
                sendNotification("You Have A New Job Notification.", alert.getTitle());
                Log.d(TAG, "Notifications turned " + notifPref + " ...User will be notified");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Notifications turned " + notifPref);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String message, String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSubText(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle(notificationBuilder);

    //Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    String strRingtonePreference = sharedPreferences.getString(AppPreferences.PREFERENCE_SOUND, "");
    Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse(strRingtonePreference);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    boolean vibrate = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(AppPreferences.PREFERENCE_VIBRATE, false);
    if (vibrate) {
        long[] pattern = {0, 200};
        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

So my problem is to notify user about new messages without annoying him if the user has not already checked the old notification in status bar. I am not able to persist notification id and notification builder.

My server sends new alerts in a continuous stream of 5-10 alerts at once, but each item arrives separately asynchronously often one after other with a split second difference.

So it becomes very annoying for the user since he has not dismissed/viewed the old one.

I wish to update the content of previous notification in the status bar without notifying user....just like Gmail does.

Answer (score 3):

First, add an ID to each notification. It can be a hashcode of the message title for example.

Second, each time you want to post a notification, use 'getActiveNotifications()' to get the array of active notifications. And if you find one with an equal ID, update it passing the existing ID.

And, if you don't want the sound, vibration and ticker to be played again, use the 'setOnlyAlertOnce(true)' option.

Comment: But can I update the contents of the notification if I find a matching one in array returned by getactivenotifications() with out notfying user

Comment: Sure, check this out: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read that ....the advice they give is to retain notification I'd and builder object , which in my case I implement by notification I'd same, but the problem is how to retain builder object as it has to be created on receiving message. ....please see my code posted above.

Comment: AFIK it doesn't have to be the same instance of NotificationCompat.Builder. Just create a new one with the data from your push and pass the existing ID...

Comment: I m doing just that, always keeping the ID to be ‘0‘ ...but still my phone makes notifying sound for each alert, when it should only notify for the first one incase that first alert has not been dismissed. I upvoted your answer, will accept it too, if you could just help me figure out where I m going wrong. I have updated my code too.